# Can Isabelle import files in directory where name has a space in?

Tags: import, isabelle

I am using "Google Drive" to store theories  But want to use different directories  for different subjects.  But 
**imports  "/Users/dstr/Google Drive/Isabelle/Galois/PreGalois"**  fails to work so I set up an environment variable $ISABELLEWORK   and found 
**imports "$ISABELLEWORK/Galois/PreGalois"**  does not work as the environment variable is not recognised by isabelle.

I have two questions:
  One, is it possible import theories from directories with spaces "Google Drive"?
  Two, can I get Isabelle to recognise new environment variables?
many thanks

Answer (score 1):

You cannot import a theory with a space in the path… unless it is defined in a variable.

Edit the file ~/.isabelle/Isabelle2019/etc/settings (replace 2019 by the Isabelle version you are using, you might have to create the file) and add the line

```
ISABELLEWORK="/Users/dstr/Google Drive/Isabelle/"
```

Restart Isabelle and importing "$ISABELLEWORK/Galois/PreGalois" will work.